# Android regain focus on EditText when they are created by code

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I am using code to create a new TextView and a new EditText whenever I click on a button. The TextView and EditText are created but the problem is that when I focus on the new EditText it is impossible to regain focus on the previous ones. Maybe the user has entered a wrong information so I would to regain access to that EditText.

I show you the code I have used:

```
public void anadir(View view){
    TextView nuevoTexto = new TextView(this);
    EditText nuevoEdito = new EditText(this);

    nuevoTexto.setText("Dirección correo nº"+contador);
    nuevoTexto.setTextSize(15);
    nuevoTexto.setPadding(margenIzquierdoTexto, margenArribaTexto, 0, 0);

    nuevoEdito.setEms(10);
    nuevoEdito.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    nuevoEdito.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    nuevoEdito.setFocusable(true);
    nuevoEdito.setPadding(margenIzquierdoEdito, margenArribaEdito, 0, 0);

    padreTexto.addView(nuevoTexto);
    padreEdito.addView(nuevoEdito);
    textos.add(nuevoTexto);
    editos.add(nuevoEdito);
    contador++;
    margenArribaTexto += 40;
    margenArribaEdito += 40;
}
```

I have used the following options to regain that access but it doesn´t work.

```
nuevoEdito.setFocusable(true);
nuevoEdito.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
nuevoEdito.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: use requestfocus to get focus back

[request focus may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069063/how-to-get-focus-on-edit-box-while-validating-user-validation

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
nuevoEdito.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I´ve added that line of code between the following lines and it doesn´t work

nuevoEdito.setFocusable(true);
nuevoEdito.setPadding(margenIzquierdoEdito, margenArribaEdito, 0, 0);

Comment: I'm getting a little bit mad with this problem. Can anyone help me?